# An exact sequence of homology in abelian categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, abelian-categories

$\renewcommand{\im}{\mathop{\rm im}}\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}$Let $A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C$ be a complex in an abelian category, I.e. $gf=0$.
Let $H:=\coker(\im(f)\to \ker(g)).$

Then $H\xrightarrow{i}\coker(f)\xrightarrow{p}\im(g)$ is exact.

Could you give me a proof of it?

I can say that $i$ is a monomorphism and $p$ is epi.
I know that $\im(f)=\ker(\coker(f))=\coker(\ker(f))$ and that $\im(f)\to \ker(g)$ is monomorphic.

But I want $\im(i)=\ker(p).$ I cannot prove even that $pi=0.$

Comment: See Kashiwara-Schapira, (8.3.4), [page 178](http://books.google.com/books?id=K-SjOw_2gXwC&pg=PA178). [This thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/18047/) might be interesting (although it doesn't contain an answer to your specific question).

Comment: Do you accept usage of the nine lemma here? Your desired sequence is obtained by taking $\im(f)$-quotient of the exact sequence $0\to \ker(g)\to B\to \im(g)\to 0$ which may be the bottom row of an $3\times 3$ square with exact cols and two exact top rows.

Comment: @commenter Thank you for letting know me the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote the objects by capital and corresponding arrows by small letters: ${\rm coim} f:A\to {\rm Coim} f$. Sorry, I write from left to right.

First of all, as in any Abelian category, $f={\rm coim} f\cdot {\rm im}f$, so 
$$fg=0 \iff {\rm coim}f\, {\rm im}f\cdot{\rm coim}g\,{\rm im}g=0 \iff {\rm im}f\cdot {\rm coim g}=0,$$
as ${\rm coim} f$ is epi and ${\rm im}g$ is mono, moreover, we also have ${\rm ker}g={\rm ker}({\rm coim}g)$ and ${\rm coker}f={\rm coker}({\rm im}f)$.
Hence wlog. we can assume that $f$ is *mono* ($f={\rm im}f$) and $g$ is *epi* ($g={\rm coim} g$), and this way $A={\rm Im}f$ and $C={\rm Coim}g$ is also assumed.

We can then draw a (bit simplified) diagram with
$$ A\underbrace{\overset{j}\to {\rm Ker}g \to B}_f \overbrace{\to{\rm Coker}f \underset{p}\to C}^g$$
where $H={\rm Coker}j$. As $j\cdot{\rm ker}g\cdot{\rm coker}f=f\cdot{\rm coker}f=0$, we get the $i:H\to{\rm Coker}f$. Now 
$${\rm coker}j\cdot i\, p= {\rm ker}g\cdot {\rm coker}f\cdot p= {\rm ker}g\cdot g=0$$
hence, $ip=0$, because ${\rm coker}j$ is epi.

For the exactness, it is enough to prove that $p={\rm coker}i$. For this: if $iv=0$ for any arrow $v$, we have
$0={\rm coker} j\cdot iv={\rm ker} g\cdot{\rm coker}f\cdot v$. But, as $g$ is epi, $g={\rm coim}g={\rm coker}({\rm ker}g)$, this goes through $g$: we get a $t$ such that $gt={\rm coker}f\cdot v$. Then, using that ${\rm coker}f$ is epi, we arrive to $pt=v$.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing the detailed answer. I understood all steps without any trouble!

Comment: Only for our statement, the first argument showing $f$ mono $g$ epi does not contribute to shorten the total length of the proof, doesn't it? However the argument was first for me and very informative, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

$\renewcommand{\im}{\mathop{\rm im}}\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}$You can use Freyd-Mitchell Embedding theorem to reduce to the case of modules. 
Note that $H = \ker(g)/\im(f)$, so you have $$\ker(g)/\im(f) \xrightarrow{i}\coker(f) = B/\im(f) \xrightarrow{p} \im(g).$$
Now, clearly $pi=0$, so then we have that $\im i \subset \ker p$. For the opposite inclusion suppose that $x \in B /\im(f)$ is in $\ker p$. Take a representative element of the coset in B, and argue that it must lie in $\ker(g)$. Argue that you always can lift a coset x in $B/\im(f)$ that lies in the kernel of p to an element of $\ker(g)/\im(f)$.

Comment: Thank you. I know the proof for modules. I hope a direct proof without their big theorem.

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck.

Comment: Do you have a direct proof?