# How to define homology functor on chain maps

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. I want to define the homology functor $H$ from the category $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$ of chain complexes in $\mathcal{A}$ to itself. The following

[How to define Homology Functor in an arbitrary Abelian Category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18047/how-to-define-homology-functor-in-an-arbitrary-abelian-category)

answers my question for objects. But what about morphisms? If $f:C\longrightarrow D.$ is a chain map, how can be defined $H(f)$?

Answer (score 2):

Define $H_n(f)$ such that the composite $Ker(d^C_{n+1})\rightarrow H_n(C)\rightarrow H_{n}(D)$ coincides with $Ker(d^C_{n+1})\rightarrow Ker(d^D_{n+1})\rightarrow H_n(D)$ (first arrow induced by $f$) by using the universal properties of Ker/Coker.

Comment: How do you go from $Ker (d^C_{n+1})$ to $H_n(C)$? The only way I found is through the image of $d^C_{n+1}$, then the kernel of $d^C_n$ and then to the homology $H_n(C)$, but in this way the last two composite to zero, since they are one the cokernel of the previous

Comment: I'll link my question here since it is related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3745192/259363 (FFR)