# Definition of Homology of a Chain Complex in an arbitrary Abelian Category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I follow the treatment on page 178 in the book *categories and sheaves* by *Kashiwara/Schapira* (which is inspired by the great answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18047/how-to-define-homology-functor-in-an-arbitrary-abelian-category)).

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. Consider a complex $$X \overset{f}{\to} Y \overset{g}{\to} Z \qquad g \circ f = 0$$ in $\mathcal{A}$. Define $$\mathrm{im}f := \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{coker}f).$$ Now we have the following statement:

> Since $\mathrm{im}f \to Y \to Z$ is zero, $\mathrm{im}f \to Y$ factors through $\mathrm{ker}g$, i.e. we have $\varphi : \mathrm{im}f \to \mathrm{ker}g$. This $\varphi$ is a monomorphism.

I do not quite see, how we can deduce the existence of $\varphi$ (and moreover it should be unique I think). I tried to approach this by considering $$g \circ \mathrm{im} f$$ Since if this is $0$, we would get that $\mathrm{im}f$ is a fork for $f$ and $0$, hence since $\mathrm{ker}g$ is a kernel, we have that there is a unique map $$\mathrm{im}f \to \mathrm{ker}g.$$ I think this is plausible, since $g \circ f = 0$ holds. However: **I am unable to show this in the setting of abelian categories and that this morphism is also monic**. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit.** It turned out, that the existence and uniqueness is easy to prove, however, I have not managed yet to show the monic property.

Comment: The map $\mathrm{im}f\to Y$ is a mono. It follows easily from there.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you! I worked it out.