# Well-definedness of Cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In an abelian category, cohomology can be defined as kernel of a cokernel and cokernel of a kernel, as follows,

[image]

My problem is why are they the same? I expect this will be some image=coimage type thingy, but can't see it.

Comment: Is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230156/in-abelian-category-how-can-one-prove-that-the-three-definitions-of-homology-ar?noredirect=1&lq=1) helpful (and the linked one)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hmm thank you very much, was helpful!